# Qt4 linux mint configuration

Tags: qt4, codeblocks, linux-mint

So previously I was using Debian Squeeze + codeblocks, and I could set a qt4 project correctly.

on debian when I run the comand:

```
whereis qt4
```

I get:

```
/usr/share/qt4
/usr/include/qt4
/usr/lib/qt4
```

however, when I install qt4 in linux mint debian, I only get the share and icnlude directories. The problem is that codeblocks requires the lib directory to start a project.

What else do I need to install in order to have this directory?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install as root or your local user account?

Answer (score 2):

According to my qt4 lib directory (on Mint 13) an apt-file search gives me that the packages

```
kdelibs5-plugins, libqtbamf1, libqtdee2, libqtgconf1, libdconf-qt0
```

are installed. I am not sure if all of those are necesssary, but you could try it.